# Как часто вы пользуетесь фреймворками?

Tags: фреймворк, php, codeigniter, framework

Я вот недавно начал использовать, и меня как совесть гложет, все решится не могу - что лучше, CodeIgniter использовать, к примеру, или самому код писать? А то так совсем разучусь. Или же все-таки не уходить от них?

Comment: на фреймворках писать хорошо, совесть вас должна мучать, когда вы уже реализованный функционал зачем-то пишите. [CI к сожалению почти мёртв](http://ellislab.com/blog/entry/ellislab-seeking-new-owner-for-codeigniter).

Comment: Каждый день, иду на работу - пользую фреймворк, иду на учебу - пользую фреймворк, подтягиваюсь - фреймворк, в подъезде грублю - фреймворк, даже яичницу на Symfony жарю.

Ищу, кстати, жену-джангистку, а то грубить в 80 символов никак не научусь.

Answer (score 7):

Постоянно пользуюсь.

> – Доктор, это вредно?!

**Плюсы:**

1. экономия времени за счет готового качественного кода для типичных задач - фреймворки тестируются и обновляются;
2. можно привлекать новых девелоперов к проекту, не теряя время на их ввод в курс дела — фреймворки хорошо документированы;

**Минусы:**

1. неуловимое чувство, что «уж я-то написал бы лучше!» (ложное).

Answer (score 1):

Плюсы фреймворков:

1. Готовая структура по организации кода
2. База готовых решений (авторизация, ACL, формы и т.п.)
3. Поддержка стандартов
4. Оттестированный код (как в плане функциональности, так и в плане безопасности)
5. Абстракции на большинство низкоуровневых задач (ORM, работа с загружаемыми файлами и т.п.)

Отсюда вытекают и минусы:

1. Много лишнего кода (меньше, чем в CMS, но тем не менее есть)
2. Навязывание стандартов
3. Потеря времени на изучение документации и поиск решений возникших задач

Считаю, что если проект планируется сложный по функционалу и большой по объему работ, то фреймворк использовать в плюс: у команды будут стандарты для разработки, будет возможность использовать готовые решения, не нужно терять время на решения классических задач. Если же делается домашняя страничка, то это будет стрельбой из пушки по воробьям (разве что в целях изучения и получения опыта)

Comment: категорически не согласен с 1м и 3м пунтом. 

  1. Без фреймворков много лишнего кода придется **писать**
  3. В большинство php фреймворков имея базовые знания php можно вникнуть за неделю. 

  по 2му пункту, как раз CI очень мало диктовал своего стиля, чем идеально подходил для небольших аутентичных mvc проектов. Кохана, Fuel и прочие куда как более диктаторские.

Comment: @eicto, поддерживаю. На первоначальное знакомство с тем же Yii как раз понадобилось недели полторы.
@vanchester, есть framework'и, где лишнего кода самый минимум. Например, [**PHPixie**][1].  
 + для того же Yii есть много уже готовых модулей.  

  [1]: http://phpixie.com/

Comment: @eicto, под лишним кодом я подразумевал те инструменты, которые могут и не пригодиться, но, тем не менее, присутствуют в коде фреймворка. По CI не могу ничего сказать, но ZF1, Yii1, Phalcon несут свои рекомендуемые стандарты организации приложения. А вникнуть за неделю можно далеко не в каждый фреймворк. Я год использовал ZF1, но до сих пор открываю что-то новое в нем, что решалось велосипедами, а могло быть решено стандартными средствами.

Comment: и все же признаюсь, что минусы я придумывал гораздо дольше, чем плюсы :)

Comment: @vanchester, по поводу лишнего кода: [в нормальном фреймворке] он не подключается до тех пор, пока не оказывается нужен.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно лучше использовать фреймворк. Как уже сказали большинство стандартных задач там уже решено. Насчет того что используя фреймворк вам не придется писать код, вы глубоко заблуждаетесь, писать придется, отличие будет состоять в том что не придется писать рутинные вещи. Для примера приведу jquery, в js для меня уже вопрос использовать или нет не стоит.

Так же если вы разбираетесь, вы сможете постепенно доработать любой фреймворк под себя. 
Насчет кучи ненужного кода, это тоже сомнительный минус. Т.к. весь он когда нибудь может понадобиться. Если вы пишите много сайтов для себя, то фреймворк можно заюзать для них всех, а не отдельно копировать для каждого.

И даже если вы будете писать свой движек, со временем он станет фреймворком. так же будет тянуть за собой кучу кода, который вы возможно не будете использовать в текущем проекте

Answer (score 0):

Пользуюсь только в случае требования, при отсутствии требований - ни в коем случае.

Причина:

Представьте себе Автопилот в самолете. С точки зрения технологии - плюс. С точки зрения ЗП пилота - минус. Вот современные умельцы не только все больше внедряют фреймворки, но и забивают гвозди в свою ЗП через 5ть лет. За счет CMS/Фреймворков - значительно уменьшается время разработки, но предлагая меньший срок - меньше цена. Не всегда, но тенденция серьезная! Сейчас меня за минусуют, но все же не поспорите -> сайты/магазины/форумы за 30т.р. 5ть лет назад стоят сегодня ~10-15т.р.

p.s. **вопрос не про обсуждение плюсов/минусов фреймворков**, а про пользуетесь/нет, я лишь описал свое видение, и не настаиваю на своей правоте

Comment: Ohmygod*able*. Современные умельцы зарабатывают в месяц несколько больше, да и демпингуют скорее готовые решения, чем фреймворки. Я даже больше скажу, одному умельцу с фреймворком будет выгодно платить столько же, сколько пяти разработчикам на plain php. Если же вы пять лет пишете магазины/сайты за 30к (теперь 10-15), то самое время задуматься о карьерном росте.  
Представьте себе автопилот с точки зрения пассажира.

Comment: т.е. вы специально делаете криво и страшно, чтобы было сложно поддерживать ? ого. Меня и 10-15т.р. за обычный магазин удивляет. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greed

Comment: Написать самому = написать криво.. странная у вас ассоциация! Но всех под это не ровняйте. А по поводу сколько писать - если самому охота написать быстрее, то проще заявить обычные сроки и сделать быстрее, а в свободное время заняться чем то еще, чем экономить на себе.

Comment: @mixalef, готов провести код-ревью вашего лучшего кода с описанием того, где можно было бы срезать углы с использованием ФВ.

Comment: @mixalef ну а что ? чтобы "деньги не потерять" а-то наймут кого-нибудь подешевле, он в коде каак разберется а вас на обочину. И не документируйте код никогда! Мне как-то давно-давно на собеседовании генерал запрягал, что вот "мы наш движек выпустим под GPL но никто его ставить не сможет сам, потому-что мы так все криво задокументируем..." в общем я там работать не стал бы и за в 4 раза больше чем они предлагали.